# Where do I go to edit the module themes of drupal?

Tags: drupal

Where do I go to edit the module themes of drupal?

Comment: What are module themes? I know Drupal modules. And I know Drupal themes. But I don't know module themes.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, that you're asking how to theme the output of a module, the answer depends on whether the module uses a theme function or a template file. See the "Functions vs. templates" section of the [About overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/173880) handbook page.

In short, if the output is generated by theme_ function, copy that function to your theme's template.php file, rename it, and edit it as needed. For example, if the function is theme_foo, copy the function to phptemplate_foo or yourthemename_foo and edit it, as needed.

If the output is part of a template file, copy the template file to your theme directory. Edit the file, as needed and [clear the theme cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176).

When in doubt, use the [Theme developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to determine what override options are available. See the [intro screencast](http://drupal.org/node/209561) for more details.

Comment: +1 for that excellent link.  However, note that you can use a function if the module uses a template, and vice versa.  It's definitely easier to use the same method, but not required.